# can't find a way to close this scanner resource leak

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, input, java.util.scanner

i have this code right
which is about cinema seats, I have been just recently learning about bidimensional arrays, and I made a 6x10 (set for this problem) boolean matrix so check if it is available (true)"d" or taken (false) "r", this is in spanish, (I can translate if you have any questions), but my problem is that in the line 50, in the getAsientos() method, I made a new object to take inputs, and I can't close it, I obviusly tried input.close() inside the method, but it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at lab05.Ayudantia.main(Ayudantia.java:24)
```

it doesn't affect really, the code works well, but just for the sake of it I wanna keep improving  so I get to understand what's happening in this situation,
any other sugestions are always helpful!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ayudantia {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("¡Bienvenido a CineHoyts!");
        System.out.println("Asientos: ");
        boolean[][] asientos = new boolean[6][10];
        for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<10; j++) {
                asientos[i][j] = true;
                System.out.print("[d] ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }   
        int[] posicion = new int[2];
        boolean menu = true;
        int opcion;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (menu) {
            System.out.println("1. Reservar asiento");
            System.out.println("2. Ver asientos disponibles");
            System.out.println("3. Salir");
            System.out.println("Opción: ");
            opcion = input.nextInt();
            switch(opcion) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Ingrese fila   : ");
                posicion[0] = input.nextInt()-1;        // nota: la filas empiezan del 1 pero su indice es 0, por lo tanto
                System.out.print("Ingrese columna: ");  // se resta 1, para que el asiento 1,1 sea el primero, (pero con índice 0,0)
                posicion[1] = input.nextInt()-1;
                getAsientos(asientos, posicion);
                System.out.println();
                break;
            case 2:
                getAsientosDisponibles(asientos);
                break;
            case 3: 
                menu = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ingrese una opción válida.");
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Adiós");
        input.close();
    }
    public static void getAsientos(boolean[][] asientos, int[] posicion) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (asientos[posicion[0]][posicion[1]]) {
            asientos[posicion[0]][posicion[1]] = false;
            System.out.print("Ingrese nombre : ");
            String nombre = input.next();
            for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j<10; j++) {
                    if (i == posicion[0] && j == posicion[1])
                        System.out.print("["+nombre+"] ");
                    else {
                        if (asientos[i][j])
                            System.out.print("[d] ");
                        else
                            System.out.print("[r] ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Ese asiento está reservado");
    }
    public static void getAsientosDisponibles(boolean[][] asientos) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if (asientos[i][j]) {
                    System.out.print("[d] ");
                }
                else
                    System.out.print("[r] ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't ever try to close a `Scanner` on `System.in`, because closing a `Scanner` closes (or attempts to close) the underlying data source.  `System.in` is supposed to be left open.

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't affect really, the code works well, but just for the sake of it I wanna keep improving so I get to understand what's happening in this situation

Java has 3 different kinds of 'resources'. A 'resource' is an object that represents something that is scarce. Normal objects only take up a little bit of memory, you can make millions of them, your system has plenty of RAM. There is no need to worry about 'closing' or 'freeing' ordinary objects, the system's garbage collector will get to it eventually.

But file handles? Open network connections? DB transactions? No, those are much more scarce. These are 'resources'. But they come in 3 flavours, as far as 'you must close them' is concerned:

### 1. Actual heavy resources

`new FileInputStream`, `new Socket`, `connection.prepareStatement`, `Files.newInputStream` - these things all make stuff that you really should close, because otherwise crashes happen. You can make a million objects, and this doesn't really matter - you can make another object. But you can't open a million files. Not because of memory constraints, but because the OS won't let you.

That's what the warning is really about: You gotta close this stuff.

The way to do it, is like this:

```
try (var in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
  .. do stuff with `in` here
}
```

Note that this is an all-or-nothing situation. A resource MUST be closed, but once closed they no longer work.

That means some code **must be** responsible for the resource. This code ensures that it won't 'leak' and by being crystal clear about who is responsible (vs a more laissez faire 'anybody that is done with it should just close it immediately'), you won't 'pull the rug out' from under other code that is still using it. Hence, closing stuff that you are *not* responsible for is actively bad.

### 2. Lightweights

There are some things that *ACT* like resources, but *are not heavy*. For example, `new ByteArrayInputStream` can act like a file, but is entirely an in-memory affair. You can make a million BAIS objects and close absolutely none of them and this doesn't matter at all. However, they look a lot like resources. It's hard to tell the difference. It's defined as defined as 'class ByteArrayInputStream extends InputStream`, and` FileInputStream extends InputStream`, so how can you tell the difference? Why is a FIS something you should be closing, but a BAIS isn't?

You can call `close()` on lightweights, it's not itself a problem. It's just not worth warning about.

You just kinda have to know.

### 3. Filters

A lot of the resource-esque things in java are *filters*. They do not themselves represent a resource at all, they merely *wrap* around one. `Scanner` by itself is simply part of a pipeline: Scanners don't themselves produce the data or ask the OS for a file handle; they wrap around a heavy (or light) resource.

The way java is set up, all filters (`BufferedInputStream`, `PrintWriter`, `Scanner`, `CipherOutputStream`, and so many more) will 'pass through' any close calls: Close the filter, and this also closes the thing they wrap. This is good (maybe the filter needs to do some flushing and cleaning), mostly, but complicates matters.

Scanner really complicates matters - scanner is all 3 at once. It can be a filter if you wrap it around an inputstream (such as `new Scanner(System.in)`), but you can also call it passing a file, in which case Scanner now is the heavyweight resource that must be closed, and you can also pass in a string constant to scan from, in which case its a lightweight.

### Linters

A 'linting tool' is a tool that checks your code and flags any potential problems. A 'resource leak' is bad (where you create a heavyweight resource and then fail to close it) is easy to program - it's not just 'you forgot `in.close()`, it's: You didn't do it in a try-with block, because waht if code never gets to `in.close()` because you `return`/`continue`/`break` past it, or an exception is thrown?). It's logical that one would want a linter to go find them and tell you: Hey, you have a (potential) leak here.

### The problem

Given that scanners can be any of the 3 different types, depending on how you call it, optimally then every method and constructor should be marked somehow: "I am as heavy/lightweight (and as responsible) as this parameter"  (filter), or "I am heavyweight" (the Scanner constructor that scans a file), or "I am lightweight" (the Scanner constructor that parses a string). Now linters can do their job properly.

But, methods aren't marked like that, so scanners have to guess. That means they can get it wrong.

**They got it wrong, here**.

Most of the time, any code that [A] has a variable whose type is `InputStream`, `OutputStream`, `Reader`, `Writer`, `Socket`, `Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`, or `Scanner`, and [B] did *not* get this variable by way of getting it from a parameter, is [C] the one that is responsible for closing it. This is *usually* true. But not always.

`System.in` is something you should NOT close. Therefore, you should also NOT close any filters you make that wrap it.

Conclusion: your linting tool is dead wrong when it tells you to close that scanner (you should not do that, at all. No `.close()`, no `try (`). However, it's understandable that it is wrong, as it is very difficult to write one that gets it right, and *usually* "you made a filter, that probably means you should close it" is right.

Having said that, linter tool authors: Get your stuff together. It's hard but not impossible to at least improve your ability to detect filters (even if it means to just manually enumerate all the ones in the java core libs - or heuristically, if someone calls `new Doohickey(expression-whose-type-is-a-resource)`, you can bet its a filter), and once you have done so, figure out if the thing they wrap should be closed. If no, then don't whine about the filter either.

### So, what do you do here

Whenever you make a scanner around `System.in` **do not close it**. If your linter tells you this is a problem, know that it is wrong, and ignore it, or configure it to stop complaining.

It can help to pass the scanner as a parameter. You make 1 scanner, once, at the top of your `main` method, and then pass it around. This is nice, in that if you want to use anything else as input for your app (a file, or a network connection maybe), you can set it up right once in your `main` app and then all your other methods will automatically work correctly, whereas if you make new scanners all the time you can't change where input is coming from without changing every method. Incidentally, now you have only one place the linter is going to incorrectly complain about failing to 'close a resource'.